# Simple Video Editing Tool?

Tags: video-editor

Can someone suggest free tools for video editing and video making? If you can include the feature much better. Hope to be able to get some of your advice. I need it badly. I am really not into technology but greatly needed to make a simple video. Thanks!

Comment: Charlotte, which OS do you use?

Comment: Very similar questions: http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/2274/good-open-source-video-editors?rq=1 http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/2389/non-linear-video-editor-for-free-or-cheap-that-does-these-things?rq=1

Comment: iMovie_________

Comment: Not free, but Corel Video Studio is pretty good, and on the Ultimate version is on sale right now for $50: http://www.videostudiopro.com/en/products/videostudio/ultimate/

Comment: @stib if you get a notification for this msg in your inbox, post a reply. thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try this list. All of this are basic software and very easy to use and learn. Hope this helps!

1. Movie Maker
2. Magix
3. Media Composer
4. Premiere Pro
5. After Effects

Try also to visit this link http://www.techyv.com/questions/software-required-making-vedios-and-editing I believe this will going to be very helpful to you too.

Comment: Since when were Media Composer, Premiere Pro and After Effects considered 'basic'? They are industry standard tools and exceptionally complicated in some respects. They also cost a considerable amount for someone who is looking for something 'basic'.

Answer (score 5):

Q:Best Video Editor for Windows (Free)
A:

1. **Windows Movie Maker**
   Windows Movie Maker is a free video editing tool for Windows and users can make home movies by simple drag-and-drop. It contains features such as video effects, video transitions, adding titles/credits, audio track, timeline narration, and Auto Movie. What's more, new effects and transitions can be added and existing ones can be modified using XML code.
2. **VirtualDub**
   VirtualDub is a powerful free video editing software for Windows with many amazing features, such as compression, video splitting, and the addition of audio tracks. As a free movie editing software, it has batch-processing capabilities for dealing with large numbers of files and can be extended with third-party video filters.
3. **Wax**
   Wax is a high performance and flexible video editing program which is good for both home users and professionals. It can be used as a stand-alone application, or as a plug-in to other video editors.However, its video editing functions are quite limited. If you want more advanced video editing features like Mosaic, Jump Cut, Flashhold, or need more transitional effects, picture-in-picture, titles, sound effects, you can turn to Wondershare Video Editor software, which make your video go to the next level.
4. **Avidemux**
   Avidemux is a free video editor designed for simple cutting, filtering and encoding tasks. It supports various file types, including AVI, DVD compatible MPEG files, MP4 and ASF, using a variety of codecs.
5. **FFMpeg**
   FFmpeg is a paid video editing tool for Windows, but a collection of free software that can record, convert and stream digital audio and video, including libavcodec (a leading audio/video codec library), and libavformat (a leading audio/video container mux and demux library).
6. **Blender**
   Blender is the free open source 3D content creation which supports all major operating systems under the GNU General Public License. Blender has many advanced features, such as modifier-based modeling tools, powerful character animation tools, a node-based material, etc. and is one of the best video editors for both Windows and Mac.
7. **ZS4 Video Editor**
   ZS4 Video Editor is another great free video editing and compositing software that provides media experts with a facility to combine photos, videos and audio files into one or more output files.
8. **Cinefx Jashaka**
   Jahshaka is the first OpenSource Realtime Editing and Effects System in the world. With the power of OpenGL and OpenML, it gives users exceptional levels of performance. It currently supports Linux, OS X, Irix and Windows and is considered one of the best free video editor for Windows.
9. **Zwei-Stein**
   Zwei-Stein is a great free video editor featured with many video effects. It can edit up to 256 video, audio, and still image clips. But the user interface is very technical so many people find it hard to use.
10. **Movica**
    Movica uses some fine programs to edit your movies and receives good reputation. The keyboard shortcuts make video editing easier than ever. It's one of the best free video editor for Windows and fully supports WMV, FLV and MPG files.

Q: Top Mac Video Editor here (Free of course): http://www.wondershare.com/video-editor/free-video-editing-software-mac.html

Don't tell me that i'm the affiliate of this company, actually i'm the contributor for that site, and those articles are wrote by me. And i wish i can help here. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the proper disclaimer :-)  All we ask is that when you link to content that you have created you let us know it is yours, whether it is your software or articles you have written about someone else's.

Comment: You write "FFmpeg is a paid video editing tool for Windows". Not at all! ffmpeg is actually free, open source, and multi platform. But most importantly, it is NOT a video editor, but a command-line encoding/decoding/(de-)muxing tool.

Comment: There's also a free version of [Davinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve)

Answer (score 4):

Both windows and the Apple IOS have free video editors that work well enough for basic stuff.
(I used the windows one for a bit before buying Elements)

Windows Movie Maker
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/get-movie-maker

IMovie
http://www.apple.com/ilife/imovie/

Answer (score 0):

GoPro gives away a quite capable video editor: [GoPro Studio](https://shop.gopro.com/softwareandapp). Nothing prevents you to use it with no GoPro cameras media. Sometimes you have to do some conversions, but it is quite easy to use, has a lot of tutorials, works in Windows and Mac, and makes it easy to publish everywhere. Have I told you that it is free?