# Recorded video changes dimensions while play

Tags: video, video-editor, playback

I have recorded a video of a blackberry simulator using Cam Studio and i use Nero for playing.

I used fixed region dimensions of width 454 and Height of 762 inorder to capture simulator dimensions to show app working.

Now i want to edit this video.I used Windows movie maker inorder to edit and add few things like:

Title

Captions

But when i play after performing necessary edits in Windows media player,it shows full screen dimension.As a result of which the simulator video looks enlarged and magnified.

I want to avoid this and retain original dimensions that i used during record.How to go about it.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Media Player by default will re-size the video to fit the screen.  To get it back down to the actual video resolution you will need to press F11 to exit full screen mode.

If it is still not the correct size right click on the video and select 100% from the Video sub menu.

As for preventing the video player from resizing the video, I don't think it is possible.

(These instructions are for WMP 12, but should be similar to previous versions)

Comment: Thanks for responding.The problem is not exactly with wdows media player but with wdows movie maker.As it is using full screen dimensions to edit the recorded video.Can u suggest some editing s/w that will allow me to perform edits in existing dimensions.

Comment: Check the answer to [this question](http://www.windowsmoviemakers.net/Forums/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=62323) for a clue on how to resolve the issue in movie maker.

Comment: It doesnt quite meet my needs. :(

Comment: You can look at the following questions for some additional software options: http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/4233/simple-video-editing-tool http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/2274/good-open-source-video-editors?rq=1 http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/2389/non-linear-video-editor-for-free-or-cheap-that-does-these-things?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for those links.Appreciate ur help.If u some across any other good sofwares or alternatives for recording simulator video do keep me posted.