# Free software to synchronize audio and video recorded at the same time

Tags: video, audio, software-recommendation

So I just filmed something using two webcams and a separate audio recorder. This means I have 3 files, 2 video, 1 audio and they all need to be synced and then I need some sort of software which will allow me to put all three files into it, sync them together (I clapped at the beginning so I can Sync the Video and Audio) and then throughout the video, choose whether I want File 1 or File 2 being shown.

Free Software is my only option as I don't have funds to buy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-Linear Video Editor for Free or Cheap That Does These Things](http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/2389/non-linear-video-editor-for-free-or-cheap-that-does-these-things)

Comment: Possibly, but that was all jibber jabber to me :/ I'm new with this :/

Comment: I disagree that it's a duplicate of http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/2389/non-linear-video-editor-for-free-or-cheap-that-does-these-things because the latter seeks extra features including a chroma keyer, and limits price to $100.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is called a non-linear video editor or NLE.  Basically you can load in the files and then you put them on a "timeline".  Each audio track and video track goes on a horizontal track.  You move the clips right to left on the timeline to synchronize them and once you have them synchronized, you can cut out portions of the top most clip that you don't want and the bottom clip will take its place since it is under the top clip.  You can also add in transitions to switch between the clips.

There is a lot more to video editing as you get in to it, but that should give you the primer you need to get up and running.  Take a look at the duplicate post for suggestions of some NLE software you can use for free.

Comment: Cheers, great answer, especially for a beginner like me! Do you have any (Free!) software you would recommend?

Comment: @ZedSpencer-Milnes - see the question I marked this as being a duplicate of.  It lists numerous options.  I do not personally stay up on the free tools because I own professional tools that are far more capable and easier to use.